# Pandas: Calculate Median Based on Multiple Conditions in Each Row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements, median

I am trying to calculate median values on the fly based on multiple conditions in each row of a data frame and am not getting there.

Basically, for every row, I am counting the number of people in the same department with rank B with pay greater than the pay listed in that row. I was able to get the count to work properly with a lambda function:

```
df['B Count'] = df.apply(lambda x: sum(df[(df['Department'] == x['Department']) & (df['Rank'] == 'B')]['Pay'] > x['Pay']), axis=1)
```

However, I now need to calculate the median for each case satisfying those conditions. So in row x of the data frame, I need the median of df['Pay'] for all others matching x['Department'] and df['Rank'] == 'B'. I can't apply .median() instead of sum(), as that gives me the median count, not the median pay. Any thoughts?

Using the fake data below, the 'B Count' code from above counts the number of B's in each Department with higher pay than each A. That part works fine. What I want is to then construct the 'B Median' column, calculating the median pay of the B's in each Department with higher pay than each A in the same Department.

```
Person  Department  Rank    Pay B Count B Median
1       One         A       1000    1      1500
2       One         B        800        
3       One         A        500    2      1150
4       One         A       3000    0   
5       One         B       1500        
6       Two         B       2000        
7       Two         B       1800        
8       Two         A       1500    3      1800
9       Two         B       1700        
10      Two         B       1000
```

Comment: kindly share sample data with expected output. data, not pics.

Comment: OK, I added some fake data with further context.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I was able to do what I wanted to do with a function:

```
def median_b(x):
    if x['B Count'] == 0:
        return np.nan
    else:
        return df[(df['Department'] == x['Department']) & (df['Rank'] == 'B') & (
            df['Pay'] > x['Pay'])]['Pay'].median()

df['B Median'] = df.apply(median_b, axis = 1)
```

Do any of you know of better ways to achieve this result?